# Getting logged out when using two keycloak instances in same browser

Tags: google-chrome, keycloak

I have 2 standalone keycloak servers running in local environment with ports 8180, 8190.
one is identity provider and other one is identity broker.
When i logged in to 8180 server and moved to another window to login at 8190.

8180 user logged out automatically, if i re-login 8190 user logged out.

can any one me with this why this hapening?

Answer (score 0):

Because i using same browser profile for both instances 8180 and 8190, recent login will overwrite the cookie, which results in logging out older user.

same thing happens even if you use same profile with different users.

**Solution:** either use different browser profiles or different browsers.